# Swift Package Manager tools version for development snapshots

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I try to experiment with some of the new features of SPM that are recently implemented in swift 5.3. Like new binary dependencies and resources support. To test these new feature I went to swift.org and downloaded latest swift 5.3 development snapshot which is currently April 21, 2020.  I installed it and selected as default toolchain in xcode preferences. However when I create new package with xcode it says swift-tools-version is 5.2. I tried to set it 5.3 like this `// swift-tools-version:5.3`. But xcode says

`package at ... is using Swift tools version 5.3.0 but the installed version is 5.2.0`

So my question is how can i test latest developments for spm from development snapshots?

Comment: I have the same problem, I try switching using `swiftenv` which tells me Im using 5.3 but when I try `swift test` in terminal I get this error and same error in Xcode.

Comment: seems like this issue has not been resolved yet: http://openradar.appspot.com/FB7691693

Comment: Did u find a way to fix this?

Comment: @Sky maybe [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62993284/5623035) helps.

Answer (score 33):

In `Package.swift`

```
// swift-tools-version:5.3
```

Although it's a comment and it should be ignored, it's not! change it to :

```
// swift-tools-version:5.2
```

---

<sub>Sometimes you need to delete `.build` and `.swiftpm` directories (that are hiddent by default) too.</sub>

## Note

Don't forget to close and reopen the project after the changes.

Comment: i love when answers are so easy like this one, and love it even more when they make sense.

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue if the intent is to use the newer toolchain.

Answer (score 3):

To use the new toolchain from the command line, you first need to export it:
`$ export TOOLCHAINS=swift`.

Then you can check which version you use with: `$ swift --version`

See apple documentation on managing multiple swift environment and choosing a swift version [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager#managing-swift-environments).